# How do respond to Alexa or Google using JOVO's tell method without ending the session

Tags: node.js, jovo-framework

My JOVO project simply answers some questions from Alexa and Google. Right now, every time I test my project using Amazon Developer's and Google's Simulator, I have to reopen the skill/action after every response. I think this is because the .tell method in JOVO ends the session.

I know that in C#, there's a method .shouldEndSession() and when you set that as false, then the next command is sent back to my skill/action.

Is there a similar method in JOVO

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, I need to use

```
this.ask('...');
```

instead of

```
this.tell('...');
```

since .tell ends the session, but .ask doesn't end the session